# Qt, "no such signal" runtime error from child class, having Q_OBJECT macro

Tags: qt, inheritance, signals, parent-child, qobject

Using Qt 5.4, I'm having trouble with a signal emitted from a child class. This is the situation:

There is a

```
class Player : public QDialog{
Q_OBJECT
/*...*/
public slots: 
  void ReactToAdapter(Adapter::state_t newState);
private:
  Adapter* adapter;
}
```

The

```
class Adapter : public QObject{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  enum state_t {/*...*/}
signals:
  void StateChagned(state_t newState);
}
```

is purely virtual. One of its Implementations is given as

```
class AdapterCAN : public Adapter{
O_OBJECT
/*...*/
}
```

`AdapterCAN` is emitting the `StateChagned`within one of its methodes.

`state_t` is visible everywhere through includes. All three classes have the `Q_OBJECT` macro.

When I try to do

```
Player::ConnectToCANBus(/*...*/){

  adapter = new AdapterCAN(/*...*/);

  connect(adapter, SIGNAL(StateChanged(Adapter::state_t), 
    this, SLOT(ReactToAdapter(Adapter::state_t));

}
```

This creates the error message
`QObject::connect: No such signal AdapterCAN::StateChanged(Adapter::state_t) in ..\player.cpp:90` during runtime.

It looks like the signal is not inherited!? Anyone having any ideas what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Try to declare signal as `void StateChagned(Adapter::state_t);` instead (with fully qualified name).

Comment: Have you just write error in void StateChagned(state_t newState);

Comment: @vahancho: Leaving out the qualified name solved it! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the definition of the signal to

```
class Adapter : public QObject{
/*...*/
  void StateChagned(state_t);
}
```

solved it. The qualified name has to be left out.

Thanks to @vahancho for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone finds here, please check your connect function for errors. I once wrote such a stupid error, but the compiler did not give any error report.

```
connect(m_pInitEncFromDvd1, SIGNAL(signalFinish(int,QStirng)), 
    this, SLOT(slotDVD1InitFinish(int,QString)), 
    (Qt::ConnectionType)(Qt::ConnectionType::AutoConnection | Qt::ConnectionType::UniqueConnection));
```

Pay attention to

```
"SIGNAL(signalFinish(int,QStirng))"
```

, I accidentally write QString as QStirng, and it works perfectly after correction.